# Generate a space with HTML that a printer will ignore

Tags: php, html, printing, whitespace

I have some code that generates bills for multiple customers on one web page.  I use the `div` element `style="page-break-after:always"` so the user can print every customers bill at once, and the bills for unique customers will all be printed on a separate sheet of paper.  My issue is that I want the bills to be a little more readable on the users screen by putting some space between one bill and the next bill, but I don't want to print a bunch of white space.  How can I introduce some extra space between the bills that the printer will ignore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a special style sheet only for the printer and have that style ignore certain elements. Something like this would work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/css/print.css">
```

Then within your print.css file you can have all of your original CSS and define something like this:

```
.printhide{ display:none; }
```

Within your HTML file, all the elements you want hidden just add the `printhide` class to them. Eg.

```
<br class="printhide">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [print css](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html). This would be a css file with print specific rules, which can be loaded with all other css files, but with a `media="print"` attribute to tell browsers it is intended for print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but @Sam152 beat you to it :)

Comment: @typoknig - It's not a competition :)

Comment: Many people on here seem to think it is.  With your very big number you are obviously beyond such silliness :)

Answer (score 2):

Insert a `div` after the bill:

```
<div class="bill">
...your bill goes here...
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Add a print stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

Define the space in screen.css:

```
div.spacer {margin-bottom:2em;}
```

Hide the space in print.css:

```
div.spacer {display:none;}
```